# ajax is not sending data to controller

Tags: codeigniter

ajax is not sending data to controller

```
    var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

        function allowip() {
            var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"
            var id = $('#path').attr('value');

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url+"client/home/get_ip",
                //dataType: 'text', 
                data: {'id': id},
                //cache: false,

                success: function(abc) {
                    alert(abc);
                }, 
                error:function(data) {
                    alert('no working');
                }
            });


}
```

alert is showing with data but not sending data to controller 
controller is empty

```
public function get_ip($id)
        {
            $day = $this->input->post('id');
            echo $day;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `get_ip` function have argument `$id` so it must need to pass on it, url keyword might be conflicting so use different variable name and get the value from `#path` with `val()` function.

It might help:

```
function allowip() {
            var id = $('#path').val();
            var request_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"client/home/get_ip/"+id;

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: request_url, 
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function(abc) {
                    alert(abc);
                }, 
                error:function(data) {
                    alert('no working');
                }
            });
}

public function get_ip($id)
{
   echo $id;
}
```

or you can do is to post `$id` in data as you're already doing it but only have to change some lines:

```
function allowip() {
            var id = $('#path').val();
            var request_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"client/home/get_ip/";

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: request_url, 
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function(abc) {
                    alert(abc);
                }, 
                error:function(data) {
                    alert('no working');
                }
            });
}

public function get_ip()
{
   $day = $this->input->post('id');
   echo $day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a parameter to a function so you can change your code like this

```
    function allowip() {

        var id = $('#path').attr('value');

        var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"client/home/get_ip/"+id

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(abc) {
                alert(abc);
            }, 
            error:function(data) {
                alert('no working');
            }
        });

}
```

and your action will be

```
public function get_ip($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
```

Comment: But it is url base function you can check this address in url to see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably the way you are getting the value. It's hard to tell without seeing the view code, but I will assume that `$('#path')` is an `<input...>` element of some sort. If that is correct then try getting the value like this

```
var id = $('#path').val();
```

Forget about using an argument with the `get_ip()` function. You are posting to the controller not creating a URL with argument values. Try this.

```
public function get_ip()
{
  $day = $this->input->post('id');
  echo !empty($day) ? $day : "No Input";  //or, an empty string instead?
 }
```